# can anybody explain me difference between class level controller and method level controller..?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I am new to spring framework....while searching on google..I found few examples which has @RequestMapping annoted at the class level and few examples showing it at menthod level

When to use class level RequestMapping and menthod level RequestMapping annotation...can anybody explain me difference between class level RequestMapping  and method level RequestMapping ..??

so I am little bit confused about their application at :

**a) Class level**

**b) Method level**

Also I found some `@Requestmapping` with type :GET/Post,whereas some examples doesn't have type parameter.

**Which approach is better ..??**

Is newer versions(>Spring 2.5) don't need parameter type for request mapping ???

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A controller must be marked as `@Controller` at the class level. The `@RequestMapping` annotation can be applied at both class and method level. If it is, method annotations will be interpreted as relative URLs (relative to the class-level URL). However, method level annotations must be present, otherwise the method won't be mapped.

In annotations, parameters can be marked as optional with default values. The method parameter is such a case: it defaults to `GET`, but can be explicitly set to `POST` or something else.

See:

- [`@RequestMapping`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html)
- [16.3 Implementing Controllers](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-controller)

Comment: If you could explain me "If it is, method annotations will be interpreted as relative URLs (relative to the class-level URL). However, method level annotations must be present, otherwise the method won't be mapped." ,i will be grateful to you !

Comment: If the method is mapped to foo/bar than foo/bar is the address. But if the class is mapped to baz and the method is mapped to foo/bar than the method's address is baz/foo/bar

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important differences specially in **Spring MVC** is **ABSOLUTE** and **RELATIVE** path.

***As you know:***
In the Spring MVC you can return view as a `String` or `ModelAndView` object.

***IMPORTANT NOTE:***

In both cases you have to pay attention to **relative/absolute path**:

1. If you declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **absolute path**.
   Namely it does not matter **class level** `@RequestMapping` and directly introduce itself as the **final view name**.
2. If you **do not** declare `/` in the beginning of the view name, you are using **relative path** (relative to the class path) and therefore it **appends** to the **class level** `@RequestMapping` to construct **final view name**.

So, you have to consider the above notes when use the Spring MVC.

**Example:**
1. create two HTML file `test1.html` and `test2.html` in the `static` folder of spring (boot) structure:
Please note that the **class level** `@RequestMapping` behaves as a **folder** path in the case of **relative** path.

```
--- resources
    --- static
        --- classLevelPath     //behaves as a folder when we use relative path scenario in view names   
            --- test2.html      //this will be used for relative path [case (2)]
        --- test1.html          //this will be used for absolute path [case (1)]
```

2. create a controller class like as the below. This example shows different cases with return `String` and `ModelAndView` in both **relative** and **absolute** path.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/classLevelPath")
public class TestController {

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath1")
    public String absolutePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "/test1.html";  
    }

    //case(1)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelAbsolutePath2")
    public ModelAndView absolutePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("/test1.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView; 
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath1")
    public String relativePath1(Model model){
        //model.addAttribute();
        //...
        return "test2.html";
    }

    //case(2)
    @RequestMapping("/methodLevelRelativePath2")
    public ModelAndView relativePath2(Model model){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("test2.html");
        //modelAndView.addObject()
        //....
        return modelAndView;  
    }


}
```

**Note:**
You can specify the suffix of your view files by a `ViewResolver` (for example `InternalResourceViewResolver` or `spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html` in the `appliction.properties` file of Spring Boot and do not declare `.html` suffix in the above code.

Best Regard

Answer (score -1):

To answer your last question i.e. which one is better, I would say in production we use combination of these two. For example if there is a user controller we map the class to "/user" and the methods say for `getSettings()` will map to "/settings", and method for `getPermissions()` will map to "/permissions" etc.

You can map these methods directly to "/user/settings" and "/user/permissions" as well skipping class mapping. But mostly we prefer the first approach.