# defining default url for controller spring mvc3

Tags: java, spring-mvc, request, url-mapping

I am new to spring mvc3 development and was facing a minor issue (which I was didn't face  with ASP.Net MVC3). I want to know the process of defining a default (or landing) URL for a controller.

I have an accounts controller where I do all account management related stuff. So all my urls are mapped to this controller. I want to know that how can I map my "/accounts" url request to hit `openAccountsDashboard` method?

Code -

```
.... imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/*")
public class AccountController {

      @RequestMapping( value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView openAccountsDashboard(HttpServletRequest request) {
           .....
           return new ModelAndView("accounts/landing");
      }

      @RequestMapping( value = "/change-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView openPasswordChangePage(HttpServletRequest request) {
           .....
           return new ModelAndView("accounts/passwordChange");
      }
... other actions...

}
```

Any help would be great!

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you remove the value attr for openAccountsDashboard?

Comment: it hits the method but only when I use url - '/accounts/' and not with '/accounts' (gives 404)

Comment: then why not remove the /* and just use /accounts at class level and add custom paths at method level like /change-password

Comment: I want to contain all accounts related methods to this controller by using /*. But that wont happen if I use /accounts at class level and custom paths at method level... right?

Comment: it should work see 13.11.3 http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    .... imports...

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/")
public class AccountController {

      @RequestMapping( value = "", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView openAccountsDashboard(HttpServletRequest request) {
           .....
           return new ModelAndView("accounts/landing");
      }

      @RequestMapping( value = "/change-password", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public ModelAndView openPasswordChangePage(HttpServletRequest request) {
           .....
           return new ModelAndView("accounts/passwordChange");
      }
... other actions...

}
```

Then you can use url like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/yourwebapp/accounts/
```

to hit openAccountsDashboard method.
Regards,
Arek

Comment: it hits the method but only when I use url - '/accounts/' and not with '/accounts' (gives 404)

Comment: see 13.11.3 static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.4/reference/mvc.html

Comment: But is that problem with url ends with '/' or not? I think this is logical, that we have some url prefix for specific controller and if you want to hit method from this controller - you should use whole prefix. If you want to hit this method by passing url like 'localhost:8080/youtwebapp/accounts', then you should map your whole controller to '/' and then map method openAccountsDashboard to 'accounts', which is not elegant (in my opinion), because this approach generate mishmash with controllers logics.

Comment: if you map your whole controller to / all urls will be mapped to this controller which is unnecessary at class level you can just define /account  and then at method level define the relative url from class like /password so that /account/password is mapped to method see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425794/can-anybody-explain-me-difference-between-class-level-controller-and-method-leve

Comment: @srikanthyaradla - thanks. this worked for me :) both /accounts and /accounts/ are working if I dont give requestmapping value attribute at method level and define class level mapping as /accounts